# Wordpress sites went down last night

Tags: php, wordpress

Very odd error happened tonight. I have a ovh vps with cpanel. Every wordpress site went down tonight but non wordpress sites continued to work fine. The error stated

> PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/stage/public_html/wp-config.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/stage/public_html/wp-load.php on line 37

After hours of trying to figure out the issue I changed the permission of wp-config file from 600 to 644 and the sites instantly came back up but I dont want to leave wp-config at 644. Not sure if its a coincidence but in my log files was:

```
141.101.69.30 - - [10/Jun/2021:01:23:39 +0000] "GET /wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
141.101.69.30 - - [10/Jun/2021:01:23:41 +0000] "GET /wp-config.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 246 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
141.101.69.30 - - [10/Jun/2021:01:23:46 +0000] "GET /wp-config.original HTTP/1.1" 301 251 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the file is no longer owned by the web user. Find out which user the webserver runs through, and check who owns the file

Answer (score 0):

Got a answer from cpanel that may help someone else:

Given that the issue was due to the permissions, I believe this may be related to a recent internal case we've filed, EA-9845. This is a result of an issue within the ea-apache24-config-1.0-17 package that was updated. We've published an article with more information on this here:

PHP-FPM is disabled for all domains after EA update to ea-apache24-config-1.0-171 on June 9th, 2021
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/4402401519255

I hope that this helps.! Let us know if you have any other questions or concerns.